# How can I randomize a list with a certain degree of noise?

Tags: list, random, noise

If I have a list, say, [1,2,3,4,5], how can I introduce a certain amount of noise to this list?

For example, a high degree of noise would be something completely random.
An adversarial noise would be [5,4,3,2,1]
A low degree of noise would be [2,1,3,4,5]

Thoughts?

Comment: Pick two random entries in the list and swap them. Repeat until you have enough noise in the list.

Answer (score 0):

One mechanism would be to create a secondary list which is a weighted combination of the original order plus randomization, then sort the original list by the values of the secondary list.

In the code example provided below, parameter `rho` is used to determine the weighting. It can be set to any float value between -1 and 1, inclusive. A value of 1 preserves the original order, a value of -1 would correspond to what you call "adversarial" and reverses the order, and a value of 0 yields complete randomization. In other words, `rho` behaves somewhat like correlation—the magnitude reflects the degree to which original ordering is maintained, and the sign reflects the direction of the ordering.

You haven't specified a language, so here's an implementation in Python since that's likely to be accessible to a large number of people. Note that the function `partial_ordering()` does not mutate the input list, so `data` remains unaltered through the sequence of calls.

```python
from math import sqrt
from random import random
from sys import exit

def partial_ordering(data, rho):
    if abs(rho) > 1:
        print("Invalid value for rho:", rho)
        exit(-1)
    n = len(data)
    weight = sqrt(1.0 - rho * rho)
    order_value = [rho * i + weight * n * random() for i in range(n)]
    pairing = [(data[i], order_value[i]) for i in range(n)]
    return [tpl[0] for tpl in sorted(pairing, key=lambda pair: pair[1])]

data = [i+1 for i in range(10)]

print(partial_ordering(data, 1))      # [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
print(partial_ordering(data, -1))     # [10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
print(partial_ordering(data, 0))      # [5, 9, 8, 2, 1, 4, 3, 6, 10, 7]
print(partial_ordering(data, -0.8))   # [7, 8, 9, 5, 4, 3, 10, 2, 1, 6]
print(partial_ordering(data, 42))     # Invalid value for rho: 42
```

Commented output is exact for `rho` values of 1 and -1, and representative of what you can expect for `rho` values with magnitudes below 1.